# How can I create a Route 53 Record to an ALB? (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, terraform, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to create a new alb and a route53 record that points to it.

I see I have the DNS name: `${aws_lb.MYALB.dns_name}`

Is it possible to create a cname to the public DNS name with aws_route53_record resource?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

See the [Terraform Route53 Record docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html)

You can add a basic CNAME entry with the following:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "cname_route53_record" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id # Replace with your zone ID
  name    = "www.example.com" # Replace with your subdomain, Note: not valid with "apex" domains, e.g. example.com
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "60"
  records = [aws_lb.MYALB.dns_name]
}
```

Or if you're are using an "apex" domain (e.g. example.com) consider using an Alias ([AWS Alias Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html)):

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "alias_route53_record" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id # Replace with your zone ID
  name    = "example.com" # Replace with your name/domain/subdomain
  type    = "A"

  alias {
    name                   = aws_lb.MYALB.dns_name
    zone_id                = aws_lb.MYALB.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that an ALIAS A record is a better idea than a CNAME anyway as it saves one more DNS lookup and is also free.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you. Your Apex scenario was the winner for me.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to create `CNAME` to the public DNS name `${aws_lb.MYALB.dns_name}` or `aws_lb.MYALB.dns_name` with aws_route53_record resource if you use the `domain with a subdomain` but not `apex domain(naked domain, root domain)`.

So the code below in `Terraform(v0.15.0)` works properly for `CNAME` with the `domain which has a subdomain`. *`CNAME` with `apex domain(naked domain, root domain)` causes error.

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "myZone" {
  name = "example.com"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "myRecord" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.myZone.zone_id
  name    = "www.example.com"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = 60
  records = [aws_lb.MYALB.dns_name]
}
```

In addition, the code below in `Terraform(v0.15.0)` works properly for `A` or `AAAA` with `apex domain(naked domain, root domain)` even for the `domain with a subdomain`.

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "myZone" {
  name = "example.com"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "myRecord" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.myZone.zone_id
  name    = "example.com" # OR "www.example.com"
  type    = "A" # OR "AAAA"

  alias {
      name                   = aws_lb.MYALB.dns_name
      zone_id                = aws_lb.MYALB.zone_id
      evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```