# How to map a Route 53 domain to a load-balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-eks, aws-acm

I am a developer, not a cloud expert, but I have learnt that having knowledge in many areas is key to success.

I have a AWS EKS cluster, in which I have a public load-balancer service ([check it out; it's a simple NodeJS Express API](http://a713a1a3a6b3a4f0a8f1fa5c3aaed1ff-650709687.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com)).

I also have a domain on Route 53 along with a pending ACM SSL certificate.

I was wondering what I have to do to map my Route 53 domain to my load-balancer, so I don't have to use the extremely long domain name AWS provides as a default for the load-balancer.

Or maybe another way of putting it: how do I change the default domain name of my load-balancer to a Route 53 domain?

Comment: You can do this on Route53 console, just goto your hosted zone and create a type "A" record,   select "Alias" and type in your ALB address as the value.

Comment: Hi @gohm'c, I tried what you suggested, but when I entered my domain into the browser, it says that the site cannot be reached (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN)

Comment: Note the domain that you hosted must be a registered one. Otherwise wait for a while (5~10mins) for the new DNS record to be ready on the web.

Comment: Yeah, I think I just had to be patient and wait for it to do its thing. Thanks so much, it's working!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Route53 record provides you the option to choose the target Load Balancer to get pointed to. To do so, once you enter in AWS Console:

- **Route53**.
- Choose the corresponding **Hosted Zone**.
- Mark the target **Route53** record.
- Edit record.
- In the section **Route traffic**, we have to choose:

  - 1- Alias to Application and Classic **Load Balancer**.
  - 2- Choose the **region** where the **Load Balancer** exists.
  - 3- In the 3rd field, you have to paste the *load balancer* **endpoint**.

This is to do so manually, if you're seeking to do so via code, then you can check [How can I create a Route 53 Record to an ALB? (AWS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919317/how-can-i-create-a-route-53-record-to-an-alb-aws).

Answer (score 3):

Route53 supports [alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html#rrsets-values-alias-alias-target) records to AWS resources.

[image]

This is an extension to classic DNS management. It is still an A (or AAAA) record, but you can point it to an AWS resource and not an IP.